# jquery draggable jumps when released on the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to figure out why `jquery ui draggable` jumps when released on the droppable!

its basically jumping to the right and no matter where on the page is being released!

Here is a jsfiddle to explain the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2wwa3yaw/1/

I think its because I have given the `div #droppable` a position of relative `position:relative;` but I need to do this.

is there any way to fix this?

any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try setting the `top` and `left` when it's dropped to the position values?

Comment: @Twisty, do you mean something like: `tolerance: 'fit', top:0, left:0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant something more like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/szmrb146/

When you append `x`, you can set the `top` and `left` via CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div align="center" style="width:100%; padding-top:10px;">
  <div id="dragme" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; border: 2px solid #CCC; position:absolute;">
    <P> Drag me </P>
  </div>
  <div align="center" id="droppable" style=" position:relative; width: 250px; height:550px; border: 2px dashed red;">
    <P> </P>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#dragme").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  tolerance: 'fit'
});

var x = null;
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    var parent = $("#droppable");
    var x = ui.helper.clone();
    var leftAdj = (ui.position.left - parent.offset().left);
    var topAdj = (ui.position.top - parent.offset().top);
    x.css({
      left: leftAdj,
      top: topAdj
    });
    x.draggable({
      helper: 'original',
      containment: '#droppable',
      tolerance: 'fit'
    });
    x.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
    x.resizable();
    x.appendTo('#droppable');
    ui.helper.remove();
  }
});
```

**Update**

Found a minor bug, we only want to adjust these when we first drop the object. So I added a class and a condition:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/szmrb146/1/

Add the class:

```
<div id="dragme" class="outside" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; border: 2px solid #CCC; position:absolute;">
    <P> Drag me </P>
  </div>
```

And the condition:

```
    if (x.hasClass("outside")) {
      x.css({
        left: leftAdj,
        top: topAdj
      });
      x.removeClass("outside");
    }
```