# How we can set proper position of dropping html element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-UI for making drag and drop web UI , but I am facing some problems during implementation of this . I am sharing my code which is a prototype and simple example of my implementation .

In my example there have three div elements : **drag me** , **drop** **here** and **make me draggable** .

Now I explain what is that . Actually I want **drag element** and **drop it in container** but **when I dropping it in container that is not placing where I want in first time that is first problem** .That is coming when I  **set container position relative** because I want top 0 left 0 .

**Second problem with make me draggable div** . Suppose I dropped multiple drag me div elements inside container and then save this (In this example  have not save option) then goes to edit so these saved elements are not draggable right now but there have same class if you see in code . But I don't know how I make these draggable .

So I have two issues with jquery-UI please if anyone have any solution and have expertise on jquery-UI please help me .

See my code html :

```
.drag {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:5px;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    color:white;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;   
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: 400px;
    color:white;
    background-color: green;
    border:1px solid black;
    }
    .dropped {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    color:white;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    body {
    display: flex;
    }

<div class="drag">Drag me</div>
<div style="position:relative" class="container">drop here !!
<div class="dropped ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; left: 299px; top: 299px; z-index: 1000;">Make me draggable</div>
</div>
```

Jquery UI :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.drag').draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            appendTo:"body",
            revert: "invalid" 
        });
$('.container').droppable({
            accept: ".drag",
            drop: function(e, u) {
            var a = u.helper.clone();
                a.css("z-index", 1000);
                a.appendTo(".container");
                console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.attr("class"));
                a.attr('class', 'dropped').draggable({
                containment: ".container"
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: There is anyone who can help me  ? please .....

Comment: I suspect you need to adjust position using `position`m where `.container` is relative and the clone is absolute. In this way, you can adjust `top` and `left` from the dropped position.

Comment: Review similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165521/jquery-draggable-jumps-when-released-on-the-page